# how application's icon should show todays date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am developing a calendar application.
The icon of application must be updated each day based on the day's date.
for example if today is 27 Aug, so the application's icon must show 27 and tomorrow show 28.

Could you please help me that it is possible in iphone or not.
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible on iPhone (at the moment). Application can have only the constant icon.
However, you can show badge with digit (27, 28), that's not that nice of course.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is not possible, you cannot change the Icon.png image which is used for the application icon.

The only thing you can change for the icon is the count badge, which doesn't look very nice though:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 27
```